# Generate D3 graphics inside Databricks notebook with scala usign RDD data

Tags: scala, d3.js, apache-spark

I can't find a way to use the data from an RDD in scala and generate HTML code that take this data, y try to save the data to CSV and read it with

`d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;`

But it doesn't work inside databricks notebook, is there any way to read data directly from the RDD?

Comment: I think it's better if you ask this question on the Databricks FAQ or forum. It's unlikely that someone from SO can answer this question because DB is a proprietary platform and as a wild guess, I'll say maybe 1% of spark users on SO uses it. As for your code I'm not even sure what that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Databricks, you'll have to collect the RDD / DF locally as shown in this example doc:
https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/index.html#04%20Visualizations/3%20HTML,%20D3,%20and%20SVG.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to implement this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219]),  But now I'm getting an exception `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` probably because can't read the data, how can I read the data from the RDD in D3 something like `d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {...`

Comment: Try to follow this guide to work through handling files: https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/databricks_guide/index.html#02%20Product%20Overview/13%20FileStore.html  . You need to write the RDD out to the FileStore, then you can reference it in the displayHTML() API.

Comment: Thanks that guide was useful